# How do you create a summary column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my current SQL code,

```
  select   
   coalesce(cast(machinename as varchar(28)), 'Grand Total:') as 'machinename', 
  (IsNull(cast(CRATE_SMALL / 60 as varchar(24)),'0') + ':' +  IsNull(cast(CRATE_SMALL % 60 as varchar(24)),'0') ) as '1001' ,
  (IsNull(cast(CRATE_MEDIUM / 60 as varchar(24)),'0') + ':' +  IsNull(cast(CRATE_MEDIUM % 60 as varchar(24)),'0'))as '1002',   
  (IsNull(cast(NO_SCHEDULE / 60 as varchar(24)),'0') + ':' +  IsNull(cast(NO_SCHEDULE % 60 as varchar(24)),'0'))   as '9999' 
     from    ( 
    select  machinename  ,   
    sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '1001' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  CRATE_SMALL ,       
    sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '1002' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  CRATE_MEDIUM ,       
     sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '9999' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  NO_SCHEDULE
    from    ven_fullreportmaster vfrm
             INNER JOIN ven_descriptionmaster VDM ON VDM.description_id = vfrm..description_id
                    inner join ven_machinemaster vm on  vm.machine_id = vfrm..machine_id
                      where  vfrm.entry_date = convert(varchar, getdate()-7, 105)  
                      and  vfrm.shift_id =1 
                      and vfrm.is_task_completed ='Y' 
    group by   machinename  with rollup
        ) as SubQueryALias
```

the output :

```
 machinename    1001    1002        9999

  ARISTECH    0:0      0:0        10:0

  FADAL    0:0     5:0        10:0

  Grand Total:  0:0   5:0   20:0
```

problem:

is there a anyway to show only the column(s) whose total is greater than zero...
So, in the above example I dont want to show the column name '1001'.

Comment: The problem is that this really isn't how SQL was meant to be used.  You could probably hack something together with pivot tables, but you're violating the set-based model of your relational system when you try and add a total row at the bottom because that data is referencing data previously contained in the result set.

Comment: hi, i got the desired result for adding columns.... but i don't know how to remove the column value which is less than zero..plz help me out to solve the above issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the totals row, you ought to look at the [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx) part of the [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause. This can produce sub-totals as well as the grand total, depending on what your final requirements are.

For hiding a column, there's not a solution for that in tsql - a SELECT statement always produces result sets with the same shape (names and types of columns).

But both may be better served by a reporting tool, if that's where this data is going (which I expect it is, given the nature of the query). Reporting tools tend to have better post-processing facilities.

Comment: i used the rollup function , i could able to sum up the columns .. but i am getting duplicate rows...

Comment: hi, i got the desired result for adding columns.... but i don't know how to remove the column value which is less than zero..plz help me out to solve the above issue

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty, you shouldn't. This is a display issue, and as such should be dealt with when you display the data, not retrieve it from the database.

Reports, and datagrids and the like generally have functionality to do exactly this. Perhaps give more info about how you are displaying the data and someone might be able to provide more info.

Comment: hi, i got the desired result for adding columns.... but i don't know how to remove the column value which is less than zero..plz help me out to solve the above issue

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
    entry_date,  machinename, [1001], [1002], [9999], [1001]+[1002]+[9999] as Total
    FROM ( --your query here

         ) d
    WHERE [1001]+[1002]+[9999]>0
```

Comment: From his desired output, it looks like he wants the total for the columns, not the rows.  Your sample will just add another column which sums the three previous columns.  I believe he wants another row which contains the total of each column.

Comment: hi, i got the desired result for adding columns.... but i don't know how to remove the column value which is less than zero..plz help me out to solve the above issue

Answer (score 0):

how about use a temp table to store the data query out and then build the output data from the temp table?

just

1.{your select query} into #t {your from where query}

2.select entry_date,  machinename, [1001], [1002], [9999] from #t 
union select '' as entry_date,  'total', sum([1001]), sum([1002]), sum([9999]) from #t

the logic is more clear with these steps, however, you can also use similar subquery to get the same result

Comment: hi, i got the desired result for adding columns.... but i don't know how to remove the column value which is less than zero..plz help me out to solve the above issue

Comment: add filter clause in where statement to filter the less than zero records

Comment: i dont know how to add a filter in the above query... plz help me out